# How can I order the rendered output of a term reference field?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a simple term reference displaying on a node, the term items are weighted accordingly, but they are not rendering in order according to weight. I'm not sure where else I can check to discover which values are being used in the rendering order.

Comment: Are you using views to show the results? You can use the ordering in there if so?

Comment: Nope, no views in this case, just showing the field normally.

Comment: I've just noticed something: I was not able to get the rendering order correct after adjusting the weights, at least after flushing all caches; but if I experimentally added another term to the field (it's a multi-valued field), the weighted order is respected, even after then removing the new term. Where is the cache for this data?

Comment: @steve if it's a term reference field the weight should come from the `delta` column in the field data/revision table (it has a related cache key as you'd expect, in the `cache_field` bin if I'm not mistaken)